# Reconstruction from category of D-modules on variety

Tags: d-modules, noncommutative-geometry, ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Arinkin has a theorem which says that an abelian variety can be reconstructed from its derived category of coherent D-modules.

D.Orlov conjectured that this theorem is true for any variety.

My question is:

Is this conjecture proved or disproved? I wonder know the related work, examples and any other related observations, comments.

Thanks

Comment: Looking in MathSciNet for papers which reference the paper where Orlov makes the conjecture might be a good start :)

Comment: I am not an expert. I have heard algebraic geometers talk about "Fourier-Mukai" transform in this context.

Comment: Ah! You said $D$-modules!

Comment: @Mariano Suarez-Alvarez: Could you please clarify the status of your comment? Do you mean that looking at MathSciNet is a good idea in general? I don't even know which, if any, Orlov's paper has the statement (I heard it in conversation); perhaps the OP could provide references? Or does the smile indicate that you know of a paper that is relevant; if so, could you please be more specific? It's not that I fail to enjoy wasting time by randomly tracing MathSciNet, of course.

Comment: It might also be good to add the "noncommutative geometry" tag.

Comment: @t3suji, well, I was assuming the OP had a reference for the conjecture. Then my plan would be: look in MathSciNet for that reference, and click on the link which gives you the list of papers which reference it. Presumably, anyone doing work on the conjecture would cite the paper where the conjecture is made. Of course, papers with results related to the conjecture may not yet be published or whatnot, but it is a good first step!

Comment: @Mariano Suarez-Alvarez: Thanks for the clarification! 

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I understand from your statement of the conjecture, the conjecture is false, although there are similar statements that are true. If I understand correctly, a weaker question (more likely to have the answer yes) would be "can one recover a variety from its category of D-modules."

For a non-example of the weaker question, if $X = Spec(\mathbb{C}[x])$ and $Y = Spec(\mathbb{C}[x^2,x^3])$, then D(X) and D(Y) are Morita equivalent. If X is a smooth curve and Y is another curve, then D(X) is Morita equivalent to D(Y) iff X and Y are homeomorphic (in the example above, the normalization map gives a homeomorphism $X \to Y$). If $X = Spec(\mathbb{C}[x])$, then the natural numbers parameterize isomorphism classes of curves Y with D(X) Morita equivalent to D(Y).

A similar-sounding statement which is true is "If X and Y are smooth curves, they are isomorphic iff D(X) and D(Y) are isomorphic (as algebras)." A paper with these and many more facts can be found here http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0304320

Comment: The conjecture was probably about *projective* varieties over complex numbers. 

Comment: That's probably true - I hadn't heard the conjecture before so all I had to go on was the OP's statement. It would be nice if there were a link to the actual conjecture, if it's written somewhere.